# Get element from python dictionary dump

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am actually working on a rest API functionality and I am able to get the response successfully. I converted the API text response to dictionary. 
 The converted dictionary is actually a bunch of nested dictionaries 
The issue I am facing now is I want to access a particular element from the parent dictionary with its name. 
 I can currently fetch it using its index position but going forward the index position might change and hence I need to fetch and process the result using the name.

Sample JSON:

```
res=response.text
resJSON=json.loads(res)
print(resJSON)
```

Output:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "serverGroupName": "Ent_Server",
            "serverGroupDescription": "Ent Servers",
            "serverGroupInstances": []
        },
        {
            "serverGroupName": "db server",
            "serverGroupDescription": "Database Servers",
            "serverGroupInstances": [
                "db1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverGroupName": "default",
            "serverGroupDescription": "The default server group.",
            "serverGroupInstances": [
                "def1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverGroupName": "dvTest",
            "serverGroupDescription": "test group",
            "serverGroupInstances": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "d"
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverGroupName": "wls_Server",
            "serverGroupDescription": "weblogic servers",
            "serverGroupInstances": [
                "wls1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am interested to retrieve the dictionary item where `"serverGroupName": "dvTest"` and the list of `"serverGroupInstances": ["a","b","c","d"]`

I can currently do that using the index position from the JSON dump `print(resJSON['result'][3])` but need a more dynamic fetch based on name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for elem in resJSON["result"]:
    if elem["serverGroupName"] == "dvTest":
        print(elem)
        break
```

I have put a break statement there assuming you do not need another element with `serverGroupName` as `dvTest`. Please comment if you need any more explanation.